# Strange issue with visual constraints in Swift because the related view doesn't have a superview

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I'm trying to create my UITableView as:

```
var myTableView: UITableView {
    let tableView = UITableView()

    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.backgroundColor = .brown

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    return tableView
}
```

and later inside of `viewDidLoad` to add visual constraints to it, as:

```
view.addSubview(myTableView)

var c = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
c += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-[v0]-|", options: .alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["v0": myTableView])
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(c)
```

but I get the error at runtime:

```
Unable to parse constraint format: 
Unable to interpret '|' character, because the related view doesn't have a superview 
H:|-[v0]-|
```

I do not understand why it happens, because I'm adding constraints after `addSubview`, so it should find the superview, but it cannot.
Can someone explain me the issue, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to interpret '|' character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39497571/unable-to-interpret-character)

Comment: You shouldn't declare myTableView as a computed property, since it creates a **new instance** every time you call it.

Comment: As a simple fix, change the declaration to `let myTableView: UITableView = { [...] }()`

Comment: @the4kman but in this case I cannot set `delegates` inside of the block =/

Comment: make it lazy var

Comment: @J.Doe [You can.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24305134/3151675)

Comment: @the4kman by setting it to `lazy var`, how @Sh_Khan suggested?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
  var myTableView: UITableView  = UITableView ()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myTableView.backgroundColor = .brown

        myTableView.delegate = self
        myTableView.dataSource = self
        self.view.addSubview(myTableView)
        constraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: myTableView)
        constraintsWithFormat(format:"V:|[v0]|" , views: myTableView)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


     func constraintsWithFormat(format:String , views:UIView...)
    {
        var viewsDic = [String: UIView]()
        for (index , view ) in views.enumerated() {
            let key = "v\(index)"

            viewsDic[key] = view
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        let constraints =   NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDic)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)





    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a [computed property](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID259), you are actually creating an instance when you add `myTableView` as a subview and another instance when you reference `myTableView` in `NSLayoutConstraint.constraints`, so they don't point to the same place.

I see you are setting the delegate and dataSource of the UITableView in your property. To this sucessfully, you need to use a [lazy var](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID255). This allows you to access self.

```
lazy var myTableView: UITableView = {
    let tableView = UITableView()

    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.backgroundColor = .brown

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    return tableView
}()
```

I hope this helps.